# inserting data into Timestamp datatype column is returning ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: oracle

Our application  is trying to insert data into Oracle database in the format "Tue Feb 26 15:30:00 EST 2016" into column(FLD_TIMESTAMP)  of Timestamp(6) datatype .We are receiving "ORA-01843: not a valid month" .

Wrote a trigger to convert the input data into timestamp format as below :

```
    SQL> create or replace trigger test_wifi before insert on ISG_SESSION_tempfeb15 for each row
      2  begin
      3  :NEW.fld_timestamp :=to_char(to_timestamp_tz(':NEW.fld_timestamp','Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY hh:mi:ss AM');
      4  end;
      5  /
```

Trigger created.

While i am trying to insert data , it is still erroring out :

```
    SQL> insert into         ISG_SESSION_tempfeb15(isg_session_id,mac_address,nas_ip,fld_timestamp,created_dte)
      2  values('5','6','7','Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016','16-FEB-16 03:05:00.0000');
    values('5','6','7','Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016','16-FEB-16 03:05:00.0000')
                       *
    ERROR at line 2:
    ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this ? Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Are you sure all those first fields are varchars? I think at least one of the first fields(most likely the isg_session_id) is a number, and you are inserting '5' which is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to_char after converting to timestamp?

Comment: SQL> create or replace trigger test_wifi before insert on ISG_SESSION_tempfeb15 for each row
          2  begin
          3  :NEW.fld_timestamp :=to_timestamp_tz(':NEW.fld_timestamp','Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY');
          4  end;
          5  /

Trigger created.

Comment: @sagi - Even after creating trigger without to_char , it returned same error .values('5','6','7','Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016','16-FEB-16 03:05:00.0000')
                   *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't do the data conversion as part of a trigger like that. The issue is that the insert statement expects the data to be passed in with the correct format.

What you need to do is scrap your trigger and amend your insert statement to something like:

```
insert into ISG_SESSION_tempfeb15 (isg_session_id,
                                   mac_address,
                                   nas_ip,
                                   fld_timestamp,
                                   created_dte)
values ('5',
        '6',
        '7',
        to_timestamp_tz('Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016', 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy'),
        to_timestamp('16-FEB-2016 03:05:00.0000', 'dd-MON/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff4'));
```

N.B. I have amended the year of the created_dte that you're passing in to have four digits, not two. Y2K isn't a fairy tale!

Also, please note that if your column has a datatype of TIMESTAMP(6) and not TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE, you will lose any information about the timezone of the data.

eg.

```
create table t1 (col1 timestamp(6),
                 col2 timestamp(6) with time zone);

insert into t1 values (to_timestamp_tz('Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016', 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy'),
                       to_timestamp_tz('Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016', 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy'));

insert into t1 values (to_timestamp_tz('Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 UTC 2016', 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy'),
                       to_timestamp_tz('Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 UTC 2016', 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy'));

commit;

select * from t1;

COL1                        COL2                              
--------------------------- ----------------------------------
13/01/2016 16:29:00.000000  13/01/2016 16:29:00.000000 -05:00 
13/01/2016 16:29:00.000000  13/01/2016 16:29:00.000000 +00:00
```

See how the first column looks like it contains the same value, but the second column reveals that it doesn't?

Comment: I have a feeling his problem lays on one of the first 3 fields which expect number and get a varchar

Comment: Judging from where the asterisk was with the error message, I suspect it is the value passed into the timestamp column causing the problem. The format of that string is most definitely not in a standard format! However, you make a very good point about the datatypes of the other columns!

Comment: @Boneist - The problem is that the we have no control over the application that inserts data into the oracle table , so we need to do something on db side it self and thought of using trigger for this

Comment: Then I would suggest that you have two columns to hold the data. 1 that has the string as it is passed in, the other that has the correct timestamp conversion. You could then use the trigger to populate the new column based on the string column. Something like `new.field_timestamp_ts := to_timestamp_tz(new.field_timestamp_str, 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy');`. Or, instead of a trigger (which would convert a bulk data load into row-by-row processing) you could have a virtual column that does the conversion instead. You'd need to decide whether to take the performance hit on loading or reading

Comment: @Boneist - Are you saying that we can' t the manipulate the data while inserting via a trigger ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you need to pass the data in the right format in order for Oracle to be able to even get as far as the trigger. What you're trying to do is kind of like trying to push a cube through a triangular hole in one of those kids' toys. When you try to store a string into a DATE or TIMESTAMP field, Oracle needs to convert it into the relevant internal format. If you don't explicitly tell Oracle what the formate of the date is, it has to guess, which it does by assuming the format matches the relevant NLS format parameter. If your string doesn't match, then errors ahoy.

Answer (score 0):

Try change   ':NEW.fld_timestamp' to :NEW.fld_timestamp

```
:NEW.fld_timestamp :=to_char(to_timestamp_tz(:NEW.fld_timestamp,'Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY hh:mi:ss AM');
```

this is your problem

Comment: That didnt work  `QL> create or replace trigger test_wifi before insert on   ISG_SESSION_tempfeb15 for each row
         2  begin
         3   :NEW.fld_timestamp :=to_char(to_timestamp_tz(:NEW.fld_timestamp,'Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY hh:mi:ss AM');
        4  end;
        5  /`

Trigger created.


  `2  values('5','6','7','Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016','16-FEB-16 03:05:00.0000');
values('5','6','7','Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016','16-FEB-16 03:05:00.0000')
                   *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`